# How Can I can create Google Adsense Responsive Unit

Tags: google-adsense

I can create specific size add units in Google Adsense like 
 * 728 x 90 Leaderboard
 * 970 x 90 Large Leaderboard
 * 970 x 250 Billboard

or responsive ad units that automatically resize according to windows size.

Comparing historical earning on my website of different ad units, I can say, that responsive ad unit RPM is quite good. But the Large Leaderboard (970 x 90) RPM is about twice better.

Is there a way how to create responsive add unit which will scale up to 970 x 90?

Comment: Read the docs. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en They explain everything very well, even how to customize it.